# How do I dismiss the iOS11 horizontal keyboard on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios

On iOS 10 there was a button on the iPhone horizontal keyboard to dismiss it when it wasn't needed, on iOS11 this button seems to be missing.

How do I dismiss the iOS11 horizontal keyboard on the iPhone

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swipe confidently just above the message input bar, and the keyboard will hide. To make it show again, tap the message input.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't seem to work in all apps through eg. Prompt. It and other like it will have to be updated.

Comment: @ScruffyDan Most stock apps should support this, and Stack Exchange lets you do this with comments as well.

Comment: @ScruffyDan, i also use prompt and am having the same issue. you may want to give "termius" a try. it is a free app that lets you dismiss the keyboard just fine. i am using it as an alternative to prompt until they get an update out.